# Is there a general rule on how to most efficiently purchase rental properties?

Tags: united-states, investing, real-estate, rental-property

The way I see it, there are two general options to acquiring a slew of rental properties.

1. Save up for 20% down, and then buy as a pure rental property.
2. Put <20% down, live in it for a year (while renting out a spare room), and then use it as a rental property.

Of course I recognize that such a question is highly dependent on the location, market, tax breaks, etc... but I am wondering if there is a general rule to this? <20% means I pay PMI, but waiting till 20% means I am paying rent in an apartment I don't own. The answer may very well be "it depends", but in a fully maximized case on both options, is there a clear winner with a higher ROI?

Comment: It might help if you explain why in #2 you mention "live in it for a year".

Answer (score 2):

There is no clear answer in ROI.  In fact, in terms of ROI, continuing to rent may win.

In my location, in the US, it is hard to make the business case for rental properties.  Even after purchasing a rental property for cash, it is hard to make a 6% ROI on one's investment.  Once one plans on learning how to be a landlord, maintenance on the property, and other various issues a simple investment in certificates of deposit compare favorably.  One has to hope for significant property appreciation in order to make this attractive.

Some argue, that by using significant leverage, one can achieve an attractive ROI.  They only look at the funds they have invested, such as the down payment, and calculate the ROI based upon that.  Making that calculation ignores the risk they are assuming as the housing crisis of a few years ago indicated.  Leverage does magnify the losses and profits one makes in investment.

To me a happy medium in the first step in investing in real estate is to purchase a home you can afford and like.  Then if available you can rent out part of that home.  It may include spare bedrooms, or a separate apartment.  If things go wrong with the renter, you can still cover your mortgage.

A similar option for someone who does not like to deal with people, is to live in a property while they fix it up to flip for a profit.  If one can afford the mortgage and materials for the fix up, this is a great option.  In the end if you cannot sell for a profit, you can live in a newly renovated home.